# Set Fill Color of vector polygon layer to transparent in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I've seen similar questions like this, but setting the 'fillColor' parameter to 'transparent' or "ffffff00" or setting "fillOpacity" to 0 hasn't worked for me. I'm trying to add a polygon layer that outlines a specific area of a forest to an NDVI raster to visualize the NDVI of that specific area, but the red fill keeps getting in the way.

Most of my attempts have been variations on this:

```
Map.addLayer(Project_Layer, {'color':'red', 'fillColor': 'transparent', 'fillOpacity': 0},'ACR282', 1, 1)
```

That fifth parameter "1" is opacity, but it affects the whole layer, and I'm just trying to set the fill opacity to zero, not the outline.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When passed a Geometry, Feature or FeatureCollection, `Map.addLayer` uses `collection.draw()` to create the layer.  There aren't a lot of options to `draw`, so instead, you should make your own call to  `collection.style()`, which has a fillColor option.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([-106, 38, -106, 33, -96, 33, -96, 38])
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Feature(geometry))
var styled = fc.style({fillColor: "#00000000"})
Map.addLayer(styled)
```

Comment: Oh, I'm doing this in Python, not JavaScript.  I tried translating this code to Python, but it gave me an error saying what was in the .style() function was an invalid type

Comment: @Zac use `fc.style(fillColor="#00000000")`.

Comment: @Kadir I've tried that but it didn't work. It still gives me a partially red fill.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I figured out how to do it by creating a visual parameters object and then calling on it with two stars preceeding it "**".  I'm not sure what the two stars do, but I copied and pasted from another answer and changed the variables and it works now:

```
vis_params = {
    'color': 'white', 
    'pointSize': 3,
    'pointShape': 'circle',
    'width': 2,
    'lineType': 'solid',
    'fillColor': '00000000',
}
Map.addLayer(Project_Feature.style(**vis_params), {}, "Styled_ACR371")
```